# Passing class into class

Tags: c++, class

probably a simple question and asked many times before but...

I have a Server which has a handle hServer and many nodes. I want to create node classes based on Server class but have access to the hServer handle.

So far I have created a Server class:

In header

```
class USF4KSYS_Server
{


public:

    unsigned long hServer = 0;

    USF4KSYS_Server();
    ~USF4KSYS_Server();


    error_t InitialiseUsfServer();

};
```

And a node class

```
class USF4KSYS_Node
{
public:
    USF4KSYS_Node(USF4KSYS_Server *USF4KSYSServer);
    ~USF4KSYS_Node();
};
```

Constructors are in cpp

Is this generally right? And what do I need to do in main code.
Something like this?

```
    auto myServer = new USF4KSYS_Server();

    if (!error)
        error = myServer->InitialiseUsfServer();

    auto myPrimaryNode = new USF4KSYS_Node(&myServer);
```

I need access to hServer in my Node.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right

```
struct A {}

struct B {
  B(A* a) : _a(a) {}

  A _a;
}

A a;
B b(&a);
```

If you don't need dynamic allocation you can do this through reference, like below

```
struct A {}

struct B {
  B(A& a) : _a(a) {}

  A _a;
}

A a;
B b(a);
```

Comment: Sorry, you've lost me a bit with the As, as and Bs. Can you relate it to my code name.

Comment: A is `Server` with `hServer`. B is `Node` with A(Server) member.